# Block-diagonal matrix from array in R

Tags: r, matrix, diagonal

How can we construct a block-diagonal matrix from a three-dimensional array in R? There are several possibilities when starting from a list of matrices (e.g., `Reduce(magic::adiag, list_of_matrices)`) or individual matrices (e.g., `magic::adiag(matrix1, matrix2)`). However, I could not find anything when we start with an array:

```
matrices      <- array(NA, c(3,3,2))
matrices[,,1] <- diag(1,3)
matrices[,,2] <- matrix(rnorm(9), 3, 3)
```

Are there any efficient solutions for constructing the corresponding 9x9 block matrix or is it a better idea to just convert to a list and use `magic::adiag`? The latter seems relatively inefficient, especially when the number of matrices is large.

Answer (score 1):

I guess converting to a list and using `magic::adiag` is the fastest way. Try the following lines of code which is rather short and I use frequently:

```
library(magic)
arr <- array(1:8, c(2,2,3))
do.call("adiag", lapply(seq(dim(arr)[3]), function(x) arr[ , , x]))
```

This essentially reduces to a one-liner but uses lists.